# Best combination of lists that provides more unique values

Tags: r, combinations

Not sure if someone could help me with this problem.

I have 5 lists of values of different lengths.
Note: Same value can be presence in different lists.

Does anyone know how to get the combination of 3 lists that will provide more total unique values?

Thanks in advance,
Miguel

Comment: Hi, please read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your question is quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really have an answer to your question, which seems to be more of a combinatorics question than programming. My sense is that if you want an exact solution  you will have to try all the possible combinations of subsets of 3 lists out of 5 (there are 10 of them). One thing to remember if you go that way is that if you want the number of unique elements of the concatenation of 3 lists you do not have necessarily to do `length(unique(c(l1,l2,l3))` which I imagine could be inefficient if you have very long lists. You can use the formula for the size of the intersection of 3 sets, which you can find for example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669249/probability-of-the-union-of-3-events .
This will require you only to compute the length of all the possible intersections of the lists. it could be a completely academic exercise: as I said, I am not offering an answer but if you are not familiar with that formula it is worth reading it, since it is relevant to the problem of finding the size of a set.